# website for algorithm analysis in various languages

Tags: algorithms

Not sure if this is the right place to post this, but some time ago i stumbled upon a website which had algorithms submitted by users in different languages... I am unalbe to find that website, anyone know aobut it here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're referring to the [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/) website. Their wiki hosts source code for many algorithms and tasks implemented in various programming languages. For example, here is the page for the [forward Euler method](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Euler_method) which currently includes code snippets in 46 different programming languages ranging from COBOL and Fortran to Python or Javascript.